# Alternative to having numerous similar functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site is a multi-page page. Depending on what link a user clicks on page1, a form on page2 has to take user input and store it in a different array. I have to have a slightly different function based on what links a user clicks on a page. Code for the function is as follows. (Apologies in advance for the newbie coding, just learning by trial and error).

```
function hp1Form() {
    var c = document.getElementById("conductivity").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("ph").value;
    var m = document.getElementById("moisture").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("doxy").value;

    if (isNaN(c) || c < 0 || c > 10000) {
            alert("Conductivity is a value between 0 and 10000");                   
        } else if (isNaN(p) || p < 1 || p > 14) {
            alert("pH is a value between 1 and 14");    
        } else if (isNaN(m) || m < 0 || m > 100) {
            alert("Moisture is a percentage between 0 and 100");
        } else if (isNaN(d) || d < 0 || d > 100) {
            alert("Dissolved oxygen is a value between 0 and 100");     
        }
        else {

    var formattedData = "Date: "+timestamp+" Conductivity (uS): "+c+" pH: "+p+
    " Moisture (%): "+m+" Dissolved oxygen (ppm): "+d;

    var hp1Data = [formattedData];

    var existinghp1Data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hp1Data"));
    if (existinghp1Data == null) {
        existinghp1Data = [];
    }
    localStorage.setItem("hp1Data", JSON.stringify(hp1Data));
    existinghp1Data.push(hp1Data);
    localStorage.setItem("hp1Data", JSON.stringify(existinghp1Data));

    clearForm();            
        }       

}

function showLog1() {
    $.mobile.changePage ("#log");
    $(document).on("pageshow","#log",function(){
        $("#logPageHeader").text("HP 1");
        var boo = JSON.parse(localStorage["hp1Data"]);
        $("#allLogs").text(boo);
    });
}
```

The above is the function I want executed when user clicks link1. If they click link2, everything else remains the same except that I want all the mentions changed "hp1Data", "existinghp1Data" changed. I currently have 5 functions hp1Form(), hp2Form(), etc.

*Could I simplify the code to just use one hpForm() function, and one showLog() function and still have it change as needed?*

P.S. I understand that there is almost definitely a simpler way to do what I want (overall in my site), but I'm just trying to nail doing it this way at the moment.

Comment: Instead of calling `hp1Form()`, call `hpForm("hp1")`. Declare the function to take a parameter `function hpForm(foo) {` then use `foo` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Call `function hpForm(formNumber)` with parameter(s) so that it is dynamic. Then inside your function you can have  `localStorage.setItem(formNumber, JSON.stringify(formNumber));` . You can then call hpForm('hp1Data'), hpForm('hp2Data') and so on.